# Groovy Eval function to evaluate some part of sql query

Tags: java, sql, groovy

I have to use groovy Eval() on a sqlquery and get it evaluated at runtime.
I am using like

```
query =groovy.util.Eval.x(sqlQuery,sqlQuery); and 
sqlQuery =select Distinct <col1> from Tablename where criteira1=<cond> AND Clas1.getDateonDBType(fieldname)
```

I have to evaluate Clas1.getDateonDBType(fieldname) which is a java method at runtime as this depends on DB i am connected to . Eval function is able to fetch the sqlQuery but throwing exception like

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 1: unexpected token: DISTINCT @ line 1, column 8.
```

I am new to groovy .Please help me to find what is wrong

Comment: `groovy` can't `evaluate sql`. with groovy you can execute query by sending it to database. do you want to execute sql query and return a resultset from groovy? or you want to build/compose sql query using groovy?

Comment: I want to  build/compose sql query

Comment: Since the query from the db can be anything but there will be a class1.getDAteonDbType(fieldName) in our java class which should be replaced in the groovy file while encountering such expressions.This is only one example i have given but there are lot of other expressions in the query which needs to be replaced.So i was trying to use Eval function

Comment: it's not really clear from your question what you want to achieve. could you edit your question and  describe what do you have before Eval and what you expecting to have after Eval...

Answer (score 0):

to be honest, I guess you are on the wrong path

Groovy `eval` can evaluate Groovy scripts, not directly SQL. SQL is evaluated by your database. You Groovy-Script could wrap the SQL statement, make a connection to the DB which then executes the SQL and returns the result.

As I do understand, you want to use Groovy because you need to evaluate the `getDateonDBType()`. Can't you do something like this:

```
String dateonDBType = Clas1.getDateonDBType(fieldname)
sqlQuery = "select Distinct <col1> from Tablename where criteira1=<cond> AND "+dateonDBType
```

This would construct the correct `sqlQuery` right in Java and you can then connect to the DB and execute the SQL withouth having to evaluate Groovy code.

Hope that helps

Comment: This sqlQuery are stored in DB and we are reading it from the DB.This query can have other expressions as well like checkforNull etc.so for each we will not be able to replace with variable.My issue is convert to sqlquery  and then the script will get connection and execute the query. We are using 3 differernt DBs's and the this query needs to be work in all three.Clas1 contains function related with all there 3 Db's

Comment: I tried in this way sqlQuery = groovy.util.Eval.me("${sqlQuery}"); but it giving me exception as Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Class1 for class: Script1.Sorry for inserting the code of line

Comment: I guess what you are missing is the `binding` of properties to your executed script. The script contained in the `${sqlQuery}` doesn't know anything about variables defined outside. So you need to bind the needed variables to the execution of the script. I guess if you search for "groovy eval binding" you will find a solution...